# What's the importance of that scene with Gabby?

Tags: plot-explanation, infinity-chamber

Spoilers ahead if you didn't watch [Infinity Chamber](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3839880/).

In the movie we see the main character Frank trapped in a room reliving the same day over and over, but also sometimes getting the false reality created by Howard. Near the end we see Gabby also trapped in a similar room somewhere nearby. What's the importance of that scene? Why are the filmmakers showing it to us?

- Frank have not seen her during his escape, it also doesn't seem to have been displayed in any of the screens in the control room;
- it doesn't seem to have any effect on the plot from that point onwards;
- Was she also being processed? Was that real?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/73xmjz/infinity_chamber_whats_your_take_on_it/ / https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/awie1v/infinity_chamber_what_really_happened_in_this/ / https://www.denofgeek.com/uk/movies/infinity-chamber/54580/infinity-chamber-exploring-an-underrated-indie-sci-fi-gem / https://www.thisisbarry.com/film/somnio-infinity-chamber-2016-movie-plot-ending-explained/ / etc.

Comment: Thanks @BCdotWEB I'm aware with the ambiguity of the whole movie but I'm interested specifically in that particular scene. Everything else seems to be connected one way or another, but why would we see her in a cell like his? Frank doesn't seem to believe she was arrested at any point.

Comment: I do not have seen this, but maybe it says "It can happen to everyone"?